# iOS OpenGL ES screen rotation while background apps bar visible

Tags: ios, ipad, glkit, screen-rotation

My app uses `GLKit` to render 3D scene with `OpenGL ES`.

All works fine, except one thing. When I launch my app in iPad and display background apps bar (with double "Home" button click) and then change device's orientation, scene is updated wrongly (last rendered image is simply stretched to fill new rectangle).

I found the reason. When background apps bar appears, `GLKViewController's` `paused` is set to `YES` automatically (application delegate receives `-applicationWillResignActive:`) and no rendering happens until this bar is closed.

I've found in Apple guides ([OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS / Implementing a Multitasking-aware OpenGL ES Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html)) that after receiving `-applicationWillResignActive:` application should stop GL rendering or will be terminated. So it seems that all is ok, except bad rendering after rotation :)

I checked some OpenGL games. They also became "paused" when this bar displayed, but somehow correctly update paused scene on device rotation. How do they achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: possibly you only need to set the `GLKView`'s `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`

Firstly I don't think that your application actually enters into the background, I think it only becomes inactive. The distinction between the `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` delegate methods. Assuming that the application is only inactive use the following, in case it actually gets put in the background then see below.

The apple documentation says that you should "throttle down OpenGL ES framerates" when `applicationWillResignActive` gets called, not that OpenGL ES calls are not allowed, that only happens after the application goes into the background.

This means that `GLKit`'s `GLKView`/`GLKViewController` may be a bit overzealous in this regard. To fix it you need to make sure that:

1. The `GLKView`'s `contentMode` is set to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`
2. The `GLKView`'s `drawRect` method **does** draw the frame even when the application is inactive but the frame is changed, but **does not** draw the frame (that is use OpenGL ES calls) when the application is in the background.

However, my presumption is that the `drawRect` method does not even get called when the application is in the background, so you probably don't really have to worry about the OpenGL ES calls in the `glkView:drawInRect` delegate method. The reason however that this function does not get called in your situation is that the view does not get invalidated. The reason for not being invalidated is twofold:

1. The main frame loop in `GLKViewController` that invalidates the view periodically is paused by the `paused` property.
2. The `GLKView` `contentMode` is probably the default 'UIViewContetModeScaleToFill'

As the `GLKView` `drawRect` method is probably not even looking at the `paused` property, just changing the `contentMode` may already be enough.

---

I would propose the following solution if the application actually does go into the background. As you're not allowed to use OpenGL ES calls while running in the background the solution is pretty straightforward:

Do all OpenGL ES calls you need to do to support what you want before you enter the background.

That is, in `applicationWillResignActive` do the following:

1. Pause your game loop (done by setting `GLKViewController`'s `paused`)
2. Pause your render loop (done by setting `GLKViewController`'s `paused`)
3. Grab the current framebuffer for the current orientation state
4. Render the current game state one more time with a framebuffer and viewport that correspond to the rotated orientation state and grab that framebuffer

Furthermore you need `GLKView`'s `contentMode` to be set to `UIViewContentModeRedraw` so that the `drawRect` method is actually called after the view's frame has been changed by the orientation change.

Finally in `GLKView`'s `drawRect` method you need to check whether `paused` is `YES` or `NO` in the `NO` case do the rendering as normal, in the `YES` case take one of the framebuffers saved in `applicationWillResignActive` and draw it to the view with regular `UIKit` calls.

I'm not sure how well this hackish solution would integrate with `GLKit`, you might need some subclassing.

Comment: I just tested in a project of mine in the simulator, the animation does pause when the app bar is opened, however when I rotate the virtual ipad the frame **is** redrawn with the new aspect ratio. This seems to happen regardless of content mode, testing with iPad iOS 6.1.

Comment: The main problem is the scene redrawn only to new (result) aspect ratio. Objects on my scene depend on view frame - I recalculate their sizes & positions to fill as much screen space as possible. So during animation I want smooth recalculations and not "start size & positions" -> "end size & positions" - some animated transition from one to another. And in case of reusing same framebuffer we see stretching instead of repositioning

Comment: Unless you start hacking with GLKit you will not get an animation form one to the other as the frameloop does get paused and you don't want (shouldn't) have the frameloop continuing when you application is inactive, i.e. this also happens when you get an incoming call or such on the iphone. The only thing you can do is simply redraw the scene based on the new view bounds, which does work correctly in GLKit. Personally I don't think it is a probably that device rotation will switch presentations instead of animating them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, comments and time. It's not 100% the answer I wanted, but the answer I expected. :) Now (at least) I know that there is no something "I've skipped".

Answer (score 0):

Implement the delegate method (if you haven't done it already)

`-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground` and unpause the `GLKViewController` from there.

From what I understood from your question you can keep the game paused but resize the glView in this method as well, but without seeing any code is also difficult to really see what's going on.

Comment: `GLKViewController` is unpaused automatically on entering foreground. When background apps bar is visible the app is in "background" state and this time I need `GLKView` updating.

Comment: @kpower I think I understand your question now. The thing is when the app is running but you have double clicked the home button. If you have a timer that controls your rendering loop then yes, invalidate it during didenterbackground and not willresignactive. It should keep animating as it was.