# iOS OpenGL Catch-22: OpenGL background rules and "app snapshot" for App Switcher

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, opengl-es, layoutsubviews

Like many developers, I have an app that uses OpenGL via a `UIView` subclass whose `layerClass:` method returns `[CAEAGLLayer class]`.

Note I am **not** using `GLKit` or `GLKView` or `GLKViewController`

When I click Home to put the app into the background, after `applicationDidEnterBackground`, iOS calls my view's `layoutSubviews` twice, with portrait and landscape sizes, trying to generate an "app snapshot" as explained here (see "prepare for the app snapshot"):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW10

How can this possibly work?

There seems to be a direct contradiction here with the very clear advice on this page (see "Background Apps May Not Execute Commands on the Graphics Hardware"):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH5-SW1

that we must not draw anything with OpenGL after `applicationDidEnterBackground`

If we don't draw, we cannot generate the snapshots.  We must violate one rule or the other.

But we also want good snapshots in both orientations, so that when the user double-clicks home and goes to the App Switcher, they see reasonable snapshot images.

Even if I temporarily change my code to fully implement the `layoutSubviews` after `applicationDidEnterBackground` by creating an OpenGL surface and drawing (which, contrary to the Apple dox, does not crash), and then I double-click home and look at the snapshot in different orientations, only the snapshot for the orientation I was in before is correct.  The other one is a super-ugly nasty re-scaling of the other snapshot.  Apple seems to be going through the motions of taking snapshots, but not actually taking them.

I am seeing this behavior on iOS 9.3.2 on an iPad Mini.  The behavior doesn't show on most/all iPhone devices since they don't support a landscape App Switcher.

**UPDATE:** the problem also happens, and happens much worse, when using the new iOS 9 "Slide Over" multitasking feature and switching the same app between being a normal fullscreen app vs. being an app slid over another app.  iOS only seems to capture a snapshot of the last app size, so after using the app at 640px wide and then trying to use the App Switcher to get to the app fullscreen, we see a grotesque pixely out-of-proportion snapshot in the App Switcher and also during the first second of launch.  There has got to be some way to fix this!

**UPDATE 2:** I have seen a few iOS apps, which I know to be OpenGL-only apps, where if you use them in portrait, then go back Home and rotate to landscape, then double-click Home, you see the portrait launch image rather than a horrible, distorted, out-of-proportion image like I am seeing.  While I would prefer to render snapshot images, I would even be happy to see the launch image. But the option everyone mentions, `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch`, **does not work** because it only affects what you see at actual app launch time, not what is seen in the App Switcher when you double-click Home, and for many on StackOverflow it actually didn't even work at all (not even at launch time).

How do we get around this Catch-22?

This StackOverflow thread (unlike me, the OP here uses GLKit but the symptom is the same):

[iOS OpenGL ES screen rotation while background apps bar visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954994/ios-opengl-es-screen-rotation-while-background-apps-bar-visible)

confirms that some OpenGL apps on iOS **are** able to have proper preview images in the Home double-press app switcher for both orientations.  How do they do it?

How can I get proper snapshots shown in both orientations in the App Switcher?

Here is a log of `AppDelegate` (appdel), `ViewController` (eaglc) and `View` (eaglv) calls that come from iOS at the time that I click the Home button once to exit the app.  You can see the attempts at snapshotting that come well after `didEnterBackground`:

```
+  189.57ms      appdel appWillResignActive
+    0.74ms        appdel appWillResignActive between_view_os_callbacks 0
+    4.11ms        appdel appWillResignActive between_view_os_callbacks 0 done
+    0.82ms        appdel appWillResignActive activation_changed
+    1.50ms        appdel appWillResignActive activation_changed done
+    0.47ms        appdel appWillResignActive between_view_os_callbacks 1
+    2.68ms          drawing rect [(144,1418)+(2,66)] (0 left)
+   44.28ms          swap_buffers glFlush()
+    6.16ms          swap_buffers presentRenderBuffer
+    9.01ms        appdel appWillResignActive between_view_os_callbacks 1 done
+    0.61ms        appdel save_state
                     ..app saving data, no OpenGL here..
+    0.49ms          appdel save_state calling glFinish
+    0.34ms        appdel save_state done
+    0.25ms      appdel appWillResignActive done
+  492.72ms      appdel applicationDidEnterBackground
+    0.56ms        appdel save_state
                     ..app saving data, no OpenGL here..
+    0.65ms          appdel save_state calling glFinish
+    0.54ms        appdel save_state done
+    0.65ms        eaglv let_go_of_frame_buffer_render_buffer
                     app drops OpenGL frame_buffer and render_buffer here
+    1.10ms      appdel applicationDidEnterBackground done

Now we are not supposed to do OpenGL, BUT...

+    6.30ms      eaglc supportedInterfaceOrientations
+    5.74ms      about_to_sleep between_view_os_callbacks
+    1.30ms        SKIPPING between_view_os_callbacks cuz app in background
+    0.66ms      about_to_sleep between_view_os_callbacks done
+  135.85ms      eaglc willRotateToInterfaceOrientation
+    2.49ms      appdel willChangeStatusBarFrame new=0,0 768x20
+    3.21ms      appdel didChangeStatusBarFrame old=0,0 1024x20

we get a portrait layoutSubviews....

+    1.26ms      eaglv layoutSubviews (initted=1, have_fbrb=0)
+    1.80ms        eaglv assure_frame_buffer_render_buffer
+    0.95ms          eaglv assure_fbrb scale ios=2 eaglv=2
+    0.90ms          eaglv assure_fbrb (frame=1536,2048)
+    1.04ms          eaglv assure_fbrb (layer frame=1536,2048)
+    0.92ms        eaglv assure_fbrb in bg: will make fbrb later
+    0.96ms      eaglv layoutSubviews done
+    3.11ms      eaglc didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation
+  149.07ms      eaglc willRotateToInterfaceOrientation
+    1.99ms      appdel willChangeStatusBarFrame new=0,0 1024x20
+    2.35ms      appdel didChangeStatusBarFrame old=0,0 768x20

then a landscape layoutSubviews...

+    1.91ms      eaglv layoutSubviews (initted=1, have_fbrb=0)
+    1.09ms        eaglv assure_frame_buffer_render_buffer
+    0.91ms          eaglv assure_fbrb scale ios=2 eaglv=2
+    1.65ms          eaglv assure_fbrb (frame=2048,1536)
+    0.92ms          eaglv assure_fbrb (layer frame=2048,1536)
+    0.93ms        eaglv assure_fbrb in bg: will make fbrb later
+    0.83ms      eaglv layoutSubviews done
+    2.79ms      eaglc didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation

and, adding insult to injury, we get this log message:

Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
```

Comment: Are you updating your UI / drawing with GLES in `layoutSubviews:`? Apple states that you need to do that "**Before** returning from your applicationDidEnterBackground: method", which means you need to do UI updates in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`

Comment: I do update my UI before returning from applicationDidEnterBackground, however the problem is that the two layoutSubviews calls which represent my only chance to draw the state of the app in the other orientation (portrait or landscape, whichever one it is) both come AFTER applicationDidEnterBackground, when Apple says it is forbidden to draw.  Catch-22!  So even if Apple were using my app state that I leave after applicationDidEnterBackground, it's not possible that Apple will know how to draw the app in the other orientation.  And so I see distorted ugliness in the App Switcher.

Comment: perhaps you can try to allow only portrait mode when entering background, so that it at least wouldn't generate distorted snapshot ... but i think this is a good question, and hope somebody else could offer some insights